# how can I send parameters to a java class in android?

Tags: java

hi there I have a class like this:

```
public class ScrollFragment extends Fragment {

    private ObservableScrollView mScrollView;

    public static ScrollFragment newInstance() {
        return new ScrollFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        stringA1 = A1;  // A1 = "mystring"
    }
}
```

how can pass `A1` to the class?

I use this function to call class:

```
import com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.sample.fragment.ScrollFragment;
...
ScrollFragment1.newInstance();
```

So I want send string to class when I call class:

```
ScrollFragment1.newInstance("mystring");
```

But Now I must change something in class...but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data to Fragments should be sent via Bundle. Try this:

```
public class ScrollFragment extends Fragment {

    private ObservableScrollView mScrollView;
    private String mString;

    public static ScrollFragment newInstance(String string) {
        ScrollFragment scrollFragment = new ScrollFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("stringKey", string);
        scrollFragment.setArguments(args);

        return scrollFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mString = getArguments().getString("stringKey");
    }

...
}
```